# The Pastel Oasis

Tags: flowers, landscaping

I'm looking for trees, flower, shrubs, or vines that fit the following requirements:

- Can grow in Las Vegas, NV (Zone 9A)
- Pastel colors : blue, lavender, teal, maybe purple
- Low Pollen

So far, I'm strongly considering Jacaranda trees, clematis vines, and hydrangeas. Do you have any other suggestions?